# How to grep a long list of keywords without a loop

Tags: perl, shell, grep

I have a long list of keywords, and one single data file. I want to filter this data file according to the provided keywords. How can I do this efficiently? I know that I could use a for loop, which cat one keyword each time, and grep this keyword in the data file.

```
foreach keyword (`cat keywords`)
grep $keyword data_raw >> data_filtered
end
```

I also tried the perl pipeline, but it seems very inefficient.

```
cat keyword | perl -ne '$a = `grep "$_" data_raw`; print $a;' > data_filtered
```

Is there any efficient one-line way to do this job?

Comment: Does the order of your output matter? The most efficient solution would be to look for all the keywords at the same time (both the answers so far do this) whereas your output will be ordered by the words in the input file, and contain duplicates if a line matches multiple keywords. If that's how you actually want things, you might want to edit to clarify your requirements.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `grep -f` for this:

```
grep -f keywords data_raw
```

So that all patterns will be read from the file `keywords`.

From `man grep`:

> **-f FILE, --file=FILE**
>
> Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.  The empty file contains zero
>   patterns, and therefore matches nothing.  (-f is specified by POSIX.)